# JavaScript using CharAt get from input text

Tags: javascript, charat

I have got textarea i'm going to use CharAt to get characters 3 and 5..

Textarea

```
<div class="hash_ctrl"><textarea name="hash_input" id="hash_input"></textarea></div>
```

Button
    button onclick="myFunction()"

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("hash_input");
        var Val = x.charAt(3);
        var Val1 = x.charAt(5);

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Val + val1;
    }

</script>
```

The result is nothing ...

Any help appreciate ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `document.getElementById("hash_input").value` to get the value. `.value` will retrieve `value` property from the input element.

Try this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("hash_input").value;
  var Val = x.charAt(3);
  var Val1 = x.charAt(5);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Val + Val1;
  //________________________________________________^^^^ typo here
}
```

```html
<div class="hash_ctrl">
  <textarea name="hash_input" id="hash_input">HelLoO</textarea>
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Test</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to call `charAt()` on element instead you should call it on the value of element so try to add `.value`, replace :

```
var x = document.getElementById("hash_input");
```

By :

```
var x = document.getElementById("hash_input").value;
```

**NOTE :** `Val + val1;` should be `Val + Val1;` (uppercase the `v` at the beginning of `Val1`), also remove extra `}` at the end.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("hash_input").value;
  var Val = x.charAt(3);
  var Val1 = x.charAt(5);

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Val + Val1;
}
```

```html
<div class="hash_ctrl">
  <textarea name="hash_input" id="hash_input">abcdef</textarea>
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Execute my function</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the textaras `value` property instead of `innerHTML` (assuming you want to use what was typed in the textarea).

Also-no reason that I can think of to use `chartAt` method.  Strings are indexable like arrays.

```
    var a="value";  
    var b=a[2];  // "l"
```